# Align Toastr Side by Side

Tags: javascript, css, toastr

Does anyone know how to align multiple toastr in a horizontal way? I have tried to change those css however all in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hack, perhaps you can float toast elements to the right?

css:

```
#toast-container > div {
   float: right;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```